# Unable to reading the textfile using Jupyter notebook in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Below is my code to access the text file using Pyspark from Jupyter notebook. I am running the Jupyter notebook in a Linux environment(Ubuntu).

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Ratings")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

lines = sc.textFile("/home/ajit/Desktop/u.data")

ratings = lines.map(lambda x : x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()
```

When I try to run the "**result = ratings.countByValue()**" I am facing below error saying "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory"

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d0433aff12c2> in <module>
      1 ratings = lines.map(lambda x : x.split()[2])
      2 #ratings.collect()
----> 3 result = ratings.countByValue()
      4 #ratings.

~/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in countByValue(self)
   1332                 m1[k] += v
   1333             return m1
-> 1334         return self.mapPartitions(countPartition).reduce(mergeMaps)
   1335 
   1336     def top(self, num, key=None):

~/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in reduce(self, f)
    915             yield reduce(f, iterator, initial)
    916 
--> 917         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    918         if vals:
    919             return reduce(f, vals)

~/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    887         """
    888         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 889             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    890         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    891 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, 10.0.2.15, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 17 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1989)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2144)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2116)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2137)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2181)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1004)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1003)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 17 more
```

Please help me with this as I am new to the PySpark.

Comment: The error says `No such file or directory`. Does the file exist at that path?

Comment: I am facing this error even though there is file in that path.

Comment: You may want to try reading from **local** filesystem, as in `file:///home/ajit/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
lines = sc.textFile("file:///home/ajit/Desktop/u.data")
```

i believe the error is due to improper syntax and the above statement should resolve it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since Manish already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation. If you think your answer differs, please explain how does it differ.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is put file in HDFS with below command then the path will work.
HDFS command to copy file to cluster. This should be run in jupyter terminal :

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/ajit/Desktop/u.data /user/ajit
```

After that the spark read command should work as below :

```
lines = sc.textFile("/user/ajit/u.data")
```